# Are there any connectors from spark streaming to google big query?

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spark-streaming

I'm looking for open source connectors which can stream data from Spark Streaming to Google Big Query, are there any ?

From what I found there is [one from Spotify](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery), but it's not actively maintained and allows only sending records in Avro format.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed it but I couldn't find anything, so I added directly *google-cloud-bigquery* in my dependencies and then:

```
implicit class RichDStreamMyClass(dstream: DStream[MyClass]) {
  /** Writes the [[DStream]] with [[MyClass]]s to BigQuery.
    * All the records are inserted at once per RDD (= per partition per window).
    */
  def saveToBigQuery(tableRef: Table) =
    dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
        val rowsToInsert = partition.map(toRowToInsert).toSeq.asJava
        if (!rowsToInsert.isEmpty) {
          val insertResponse = tableRef.insert(rowsToInsert)
          if (insertResponse.hasErrors) 
            logger.error(s"${insertResponse.getInsertErrors.values()}")
      }
    }
  }
}

/** Creates [[RowToInsert]] for BigQuery by mapping the field of a 
  * [[MyClass]]. */
def toRowToInsert(myClass: MyClass): RowToInsert = {
  val fields = Map(
    "timestamp" -> myClass.timestamp,
    "name" -> myClass.name
  ).asJava
  RowToInsert.of(s"${myClass.key}", fields)
}
```

Be careful that *insert* method can't insert more than 10k elements at a time, so I also have this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition",
    (10000 / config.spark.window).toString)
```

*tableRef* is an instance of *com.google.cloud.bigquery.Table*.